# Seating arrangements

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

A class has 20 students. The classroom consists of 20 desks, with 4 desks in each of 5 different rows. Amy, Bob, Chloe, and David are all friends, and would like to sit in the same row.  How many possible seating arrangements are there such that Amy, Bob, Chloe, and David are all in the same row?

My work: 
If I use the formula $n!/k!(n-k)!$ then plug in the numbers where $n=20$ and $k=4$ it would be $\frac{20!}{4!(20-4)!}=\frac{20!}{4!16!}$.

Comment: Please include your attempt on the question.

Comment: How many different ways can the three of them sit in the same row if there is only one row?

Comment: Is k = 4 because that is the number of students who are sitting next to each other in the row?  I get confused as to whether that is correct or whether k would = 5 because that is the number of possible rows for the students to sit.

Answer (score 1):

The group of friends will occupy an entire row. There are $\binom{5}{1}$ ways for them to do so. There are $4!$ ways they can sit in the row. Then there are $16!$ ways to fill the other desks. So $5 \cdot 4! \cdot 16!$

Comment: Well explained.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I am so confused by factorials and the n choose k equation.

Comment: Factorial is just a shorthand way to multiply a bunch of elements that decrease by 1 each time. Take the 4! ways to arrange the friends in a row. The first seat there are 4 people that could fill it. The second seat there are 3 people that could fill it (because someone is sitting in the first seat now). The third seat there are 2 people left (because two of the four friends are now occupying seats one and two), and the last seat just has 1 person left. So you have $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 24$ Number of a ways the friends can sit. Which we can express as $4!$. Does that make sense?

Comment: That does make sense.  Thank you very much!!